# How to connect VM by just hostname without IP and my username

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to set up my VMs and I'd like to ask for support. I am a bit new and can someone help with configuring my VM1 for connecting to VM2 just by the name of VM2 (without IP and username. Instead of "ssh username@IP")?

- VM1 is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- VM2 is CentOS Linux 7

Comment: If `username` is the same on source and destination you can simply omit it (and the `@`)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us whether VM1 and VM2 are Linux or Windows. If they're Linux which distribution are you using?

Comment: hi, i've update. VM1 is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS VM2 is CentOS Linux 7

Comment: What software is used to virtualize OS'es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and quickest solution is to edit your `/etc/hosts` file (on Windows it's at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`).

Add a line like this to your VM1 machine, making sure that where I have used `192.168.56.2` you use the correct IP address for vm2, and where I have used `vm2.example.com` you put the definitively correct name for `vm2`. If vm2 has other different names you can add them to the same line. Ensure that the first name is the definitive (canonical) name.

```
192.168.56.2    vm2.example.com vm2
```

Now do the same on your VM2 machine, but add a line for VM1.